# Prove that every finite group is generated by its cyclic subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to prove that every finite group is generated by its cyclic subgroups.

Let $|G|=n$ and $G=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_n\rangle$. Then $G=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_n\rangle\leq \bigl\langle\langle g_1\rangle,\ldots,\langle g_n\rangle\bigr\rangle\leq G$, since every $\langle g_i\rangle \leq G$. Hence $G=\bigl\langle\langle g_1\rangle ,\ldots,\langle g_n\rangle\bigr\rangle$.

That's the right way to solve this problem? if it's not, how can I show it?

Comment: What do you mean by $G$ being generated by its cyclic subgroups? That $G$ is the union of all those subgroups?

Comment: every group is generated by its cyclic subgroups, right? it's generated by its set of elements, and any element is contained in the cyclic subgroup it generates.

Comment: Why are you assuming that $G$ is finite? It seems clear that every group, finite or infinite, is generated by its cyclic subgroups, because, if $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by the cyclic subgroups of the group $G$, then for all $g \in G$ we have $g \in \langle g \rangle \le H$, so $H=G$.

Comment: In fact, every group is the union of its cyclic groups

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your reasoning is correct and it generalizes to the case where $G$ is not necessarily finite:

$$G = \langle g : g \in G \rangle \subseteq \langle \langle g \rangle : g \in G \rangle \subseteq G.$$